How to fix flickering when uploading css to a website
I have an extension that should change styles on the button, but when I try to add a style:
Eliminate flash of unstyled content
I searched on similar articles, but there for custom sites where you need to write something in html, but in my case I am writing an extension and do not have access to html until the page itself is loaded
let css = chrome.runtime.getURL("css/black.css")
let head = document.querySelector("head")
head.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${css}">`)

Then before loading my css, the css that loaded the site works for a second and it's not very beautifulMy
My manifest:
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["./scripts/material.js", "./scripts/content.js"],
        "matches": ["https://funpay.com/*"]
    }],
    "host_permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "scripting",
        "storage",
        "cookies",
        "activeTab",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": [ "css/black.css" ],
        "matches": ["https://funpay.com/*"]
    }]

My black.css:
body {background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40) !important;}

Is there any way to avoid this flickering?
What would it be like when uploading via manifest to content_scripts, that is, the page loads immediately with my style
recorde: https://youtu.be/mzb6Ta0BG0o
From the beginning, I tried to add css to the manifest in contents scripts, but in this case I can't remove it or interact with it in any way.

Protip: Your instances of let can and probably should be const. Only use let for values that you expect to change. Even arrays and objects can be const while still having elements and properties updated.
